# How to show something only on a certain screen size in Bootstrap?

Tags: html, bootstrap-4

I want to be able to show an image in the html only on `md` screens. I was thinking about hiding the image from `sm` and down, and hiding from `lg` and up.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

In Bootstrap v4+, you can use the classes `d-none d-md-block d-lg-none` to make the content only visible on medium (`md`) screen sizes.

`d-none` - Hidden on all viewports

`d-md-block` - Visible on medium and above

`d-lg-none` - Hidden on large and above

```
<div class="d-none d-md-block d-lg-none">
  <img src="" alt="alternate text" />
</div>
```

From the [docs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/utilities/display/#hiding-elements):

> To hide elements simply use the `.d-none` class or one of the `.d-{sm,md,lg,xl}-none` classes for any responsive screen variation.
>
> To show an element only on a given interval of screen sizes you can combine one `.d-*-none` class with a `.d-*-*` class, for example `.d-none .d-md-block .d-xl-none` will hide the element for all screen sizes except on medium and large devices.

Comment: How interesting... so it seems that Bootstrap 4 allows you to declare these explicit classes instead of messing around with media queries, which is super.

Comment: I made a sample pen for this. Basically what i want to do is make it so a image appears below the base 'fire' image if the screen is ```md```. The image appears, but they overlap instead of appearing below the fire image. Why isn't my class ```column``` working? This is using the code you provided--> https://codepen.io/Mike-was-here123/pen/EowXOm?editors=1000

Comment: @Leed  The fire image will only appear on large screens based on the utility classes you're using and the wheel image will only be visible on medium screens. So, there's no overlap. And I don't think there's a `column` class provided by bootstrap 4.

Comment: How do i vertically align then? Let me guess, its over complicated as usual.

Comment: Can you please edit your post to explain what each class here means, and how to modify it according to different requirements (like if I only want it on a `lg` screen).

Comment: @jewishspiderweb Done. Thanks for the comment!

Comment: It's written great! Thanks for editing it.

Answer (score 0):

User the visible-'blah' class to only show something on one size. Use the hidden-'blah' to show something on all sizes besides 'blah'